# History API - tell browser to stay on index.html, regardless of the url

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am making one-page web on my school project. I am using very simple history API, to just change the URL so user thinks he is on another page (but I am hiding and displaying different elements on a page)
It looks like this:

*www.mypage.com/main
www.mypage.com/slideshow*

When I am using the application with back/forward history buttons it works fine, but when I want to reload the page, the browser tries to load that fake URL and that cause a crash of course. How do I manage to stay always on index.html no matter what url is displayed to the user please?

I tried to manage this with htaccess, but I wasn't sucessful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not using a back-end, which is the only way to achieve your desired result. (If my assumption is correct) The browser gives error (cannot load `/slideshow` after refresh) because it is trying to fetch that file (from you local machine) but that does not exist. [SO answer explaining this well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/4424311).

So in your example you should instruct the back-end to render the same *view* for all routes (using a wildcard), and do the displaying on front-end based on the given url.

You do not have to use React-Router, but instead create a router-handling function which runs at each refresh (that is, when your javascript is loaded) which tells your page what to render based on what route (or url, call them as you like).

*(you will know that the javascript will be run for every url, because the back-end already handles routing with the wildcard, `*`)*

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but I forgot to say that I am not allowed to use back-end, because it's only front-end application. So it's not possible you say? :/
I thought it would be possible with htaccess rewrite - that I will write some rule that www.myweb.com/slideshow means actually www.myweb.com/index.html. That would't work? (if it would, I am not sure how to write it)

Comment: I do not know a lot about .htaccess (so maybe you should double check what I am going to say), but as far as I know about it, .htaccess only runs on Apache web server (that is, you will use back-end related things). Using only front-end technologies, it is not possible to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite all requests to only one URL, you can do so with just

```
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```